# javascript multi array push

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to make a multidimensional array in javascript?

It should look like this:

```
$cars = array
(
array("Volvo",22,18),
array("BMW",15,13),
array("Saab",5,2),
array("Land Rover",17,15)
);
```

But I need to use `$cars.push()`; to first add all data for the first rows (the cars). Then the data "22", "15", "5" and "17". Then "18", "13", "2" and "15".

Then it should be printed in the same order as the original array (table-view).

**EDIT**
LIKE this:

```
var cars = [];

cars.push("Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Land Rover");
cars.push(22, 15, 5, 17);
cars.push(18, 13, 2, 15);
```

and print it like this to html

Volvo, 22, 18

BMW, 15 13

Saab, 5, 2

Land Rover, 17, 15

Comment: `var cars = [ [ "Volve", 22, 18 ], [ "BMW", 15, 13 ] ];`

Comment: But how do i first add the Volvo. And then add the BMW? Not a one-liner

Comment: I need first to add the cars, the the other data.

Comment: please explain the data structure of the target.

Comment: `cars.push(["Volvo", 22, 18])`...?! – Tell us more about *why* you want to do it in this peculiar order and we can tell you how to actually solve your problem.

Comment: so where do you start from? from volvo, bmw or from volvo, 22

Comment: @deceze Its because it should print it to a text file. Then I need to do it in this order because I don't can use html table design.

Comment: You can simply output it to the file in whatever order you need, without restructuring the array...

Comment: But how? if i create the array as above (my edit)

Answer (score 0):

You could refer the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Creating_a_two-dimensional_array).

As @sampson suggested in the comment above in your case it is,

```
 var cars = [ 
              [ "Volve", 22, 18 ], 
              [ "BMW", 15, 13 ],
              [ "Saab", 5, 2],
              [ "Land Rover", 17, 15]
            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild the array with the change of position `i` and `j`. And you can switch it from one appearance to the other one.

```js
function transpose(source, target) {
    source.forEach(function (a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j) {
            target[j] = target[j] || []
            target[j][i] = b;
        });
    });
}

var cars = [["Volvo", 22, 18], ["BMW", 15, 13], ["Saab", 5, 2], ["Land Rover", 17, 15]],
    pCars = [];

transpose(cars, pCars);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(pCars, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
cars = [];
transpose(pCars, cars);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(cars, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: What if my array look like this.

    var cars = [
        ["Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Land Rover"],
        [22, 15, 5, 17],
        [18, 13, 2, 15]
    ];

Comment: I supposed you're looking for the word "transpose" rather than "transform".

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make a multidimensional array in javascript?

Yes, it is.

But that doesn't seem to be your question. Rather, your question seems to be, if I have an array of arrays, where the first subarray contains values for field 1, the second subarray contains values for field 2, and so on, then how do I re-organize this into in array of arrays where each subarray contains all fields for one object.

As another responder mentioned, this is array transposition. A simple way is:

```
function transpose(a) {
  return a[0] . map((col, i) => a . map(row => row[i]));
}
```

Use this as:

```
var cars = [];

cars.push(["Volvo", "BMW", "Saab", "Land Rover"]);
cars.push([22, 15, 5, 17]);
cars.push([18, 13, 2, 15]);

console.log(transpose(cars));
```

Comment: Is it then possible to loop through the array like variables: cars[0] (volvo) cars[1] (22) cars[2] (18)

Comment: Suggest reading up on the basics of JS arrays and loops. Also run the code above and examine the internal structure of `transpose(cars)`.